# Firebird error "username and password are not defined. contact your database administrator"

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird1.5

I am writing a program in C# winforms, using FirebirdClient and also Firebird 1.5 embedded to connect to a local database. Here is the code I used to connect to Firebird 2.5 version, where the connection happened normally. But it doesn't on version 1.5

```
FbConnection connecting_firebird = new FbConnection(@"Server=localhost; User=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey; ServerType=1; ClientLibrary=Resources\firebird1.5\fbclient.dll; CHARSET=NONE; Pooling =false; Database=D:\111.GDB");
connecting_firebird.Open();
```

After that, I get the error "your user name and password are not defined. ask your database administrator firebird". As far as I know, embedded server does not store login and password data, but it was enough to specify standard data, and connect happened on version 2.5, but it does not happen on version 1.5

Tried different connection combinations, and different databases. But it did not give any result. I also tried different password combinations, but that also left me without results.

Attached is a sample code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SQLite;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
    using FirebirdSql.Data.Services;
    
    namespace Project1
    {
        public partial class ClearForm: Form
        {
            public ClearForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        FbConnection connecting_firebird = new FbConnection(@"Server=localhost; ServerType=1; User=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey; ClientLibrary=D:\firebird1.5\fbembed.dll; CHARSET=NONE; Pooling =false; Database=D:\111.FDB");
        connecting_firebird.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("True", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + "Text: : " + ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC Firebird 1.5 has no embedded version.

Comment: @user13964273 https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-1-5/ Maybe I'm wrong. But on the official website there is a link to download the embedded version

Comment: Indeed. But the library inside has name fbembed.dll, not fbclient.dll as in your code.

Comment: Firebird 1.5 has been end-of-life since 2009, and has known security issues. You shouldn't be using such an old version of Firebird. Supported versions are Firebird 3.0 and 4.0.

Comment: In any case, given there is only a 32-bit version of Firebird 1.5, make sure your C# application is compiled as 32-bits (AnyCPU might work as well, but not 100% sure), and as user13964273 says, make sure you point to fbembed.dll, not fbclient.dll.

Comment: @user13964273 That's the way it's supposed to be as far as I know. In any case, the result is the same with the old name as with the new one.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Unfortunately I have to use version 1.5. The application is written for 32-bit, of that I am sure. Renaming the file gives the same result in both cases

Comment: What happens if you specify an absolute path to the DLL?

Comment: In any case, you really need to provide a [mre] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Added sample code in the header. I did as you said, it didn't give any results

Comment: Ok, I'll see if I can reproduce it, but probably somewhere in the weekend.

Comment: "Server=localhost" is really strange for embedded mode.

Comment: @user13964273 As far as I'm aware it is ignored by the driver when using `ServerType=1` (which means: use embedded).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In no way Firebird Embedded 1.5 can produce subj error because code throwing it is completely removed out by `#ifndef EMBEDDED`. If the error is received from fbembed.dll it means that it has connected to a real server and received the error from there.

Comment: @user13964273 Not necessarily: it is possible that the Firebird .NET provider generates this error itself under some conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to downgrade the Nuget FirebirdClient package to the lowest version(2.6.5). Surely this is not the most extreme working version to work with Firebird 1.5. I will have to find a working one. But the topic is closed. I hope someone will be useful.

Comment: Good to hear you found the cause. Likely the driver is trying to use methods loaded in newer versions of fbclient/fbembed. Alternatively, Firebird 1.5 database can be opened by Firebird 2.5 embedded. Why not just use Firebird 2.5 embedded? Or are you relying on some of the old behaviors implemented in Firebird 1.5?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you. Unfortunately I am writing a program for a database, not a database for a program. I am forced to use version 1.5

Comment: "Program for a database" and embedded usage don't match. Existing databases used to be on server.